# for loop only runs 21 times

Tags: python, csv

Hello i want to write my list to a .csv file.
This is my code

```
def writeCsv(self, content):
    filename = 'data.csv'
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    header = 'index;title;img;link;views;brand;\n'
    f.write(header)

    #print(len(content))
    i = 0
    for c in content:
        f.write(c['index'] + ";" + c['title'] + ';' + c['img'] + ';' + c['link'] + ';' + c['views'] + ";\n")
        #i += 1
        #print(i)

    f.close()
```

My problem is that `len(content)` returns `72` but the loop only runs 21 times. (I print `i` every time in the loop and my .csv file only has 21 lines.)

Is there some limit or unknown parameter i miss on the `write()` function?

Update: I used Sayse´s solution but added `encoding='utf-8'`. The probem was an illegal charater in line 22

Comment: How do you know it only runs 21 times? Why not use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)?

Comment: I print i every time in the loop and my .csv file only has 21 lines

Comment: Is there an element in content that doesn't have all the keys you are calling? Perhaps it's bonking out on a key error.

Comment: Agree. You can replace c['index'] with c.get('index', '') and so on to avoid exceptions.

Comment: Your code looks fine. You need to provide a [mre]. See [ask] if you want other advice.

Comment: Try using a debugger such as https://github.com/alexmojaki/snoop

Comment: `print( c)` could help you => inside the loop. Could you show us?

Comment: BTW it's better to use `with` statements for opening files, but using the `csv` module would be better. And you might want to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get multiple items from a dict.

Comment: 'â\x80\x9cextra specialâ\x80\x9d' i found this in line 22 so I guess that this are illegal characters. so how do i prevent characters like that get in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the only thing that could cause this is malformed data (probably line 22) and you catching the broader exception.

Regardless, you should just use the csv modules [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

```
from csv import DictWriter
def writeCsv(self, content):
    filename = 'data.csv'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        field_names = ["index","title","img","link","views","brand"]
        dict_writer = DictWriter(f, field_names, delimiter=";")
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(content)
```

Comment: very nice but when I use your code it only writes in every second line. how can I avoid this?

Comment: @lukaslanger - try opening the file with a different line sep - `open(filename, "w", newline="")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this perhaps:

```
    def writeCsv(self, content):
        filename = 'data.csv'
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        header = 'index;title;img;link;views;brand'
        f.write(header)

        #print(len(content))
        i = 0
        for c in content:
            try:
                f.write(";\n"+";".join([c[k] for k in header.split(";")]))
            except KeyError:
                print(c)
            i += 1
            print(i)
        f.write(";")
        f.close()
```

Using the header as your indexes is cleaner imo and wrapping your explicit key access in error handling could help you get through some snags. Also based on how you are writing you output file you will have an empty line at the end of your file, presuming that you have amalgamated your data from some number of similar files you likely have empty elements in your list.

Comment: i run the code and i printed every c, so does that mean that my array is wrong initialised?

Comment: No you have to switch brand to views in the header.